# Difference in Clock Generation

Tags: verilog, clock

What is the difference between the following codes ?

```
initial begin
  clk = 0 ;
  forever begin
    #5  clk =   ~clk;
  end
end


initial begin
  clk = 0 ;
  forever begin
    clk = #5  ~clk;
  end
end
```

I do know the difference between Inertial and Transport Delays and I know that clock is generated in both the cases(with some Phase difference between the two ), but I want to know how the simulator reacts to the following codes.Is it the same or different ? Like how many events are taken into consideration while calculating the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two from a usage point:

`#5 clk = ~clk;` means wait 5 time steps then execute `clk = ~clk;`

For Wires `B = #5  A;` means B is assigned to A from 5 timestep ago. A leads B by 5 timesteps. If B is changed to A `A = #5  A;`

```
wire B;
assign B= #5 A;
```

Usage for a wire is covered by the [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section **6.7 Net declarations**

From @new2androids update syntax `A = #5 B;`, for a registers is different from that of a wire. B is checked every 5 time units and A is assigned the value immediately. Which is why it works for testbench clock generation.

As to how the simulator reacts, there may be some standard scheduling practises that others can comment on but to a degree it may depend on the simulator you are using.

@new2android Provided the follwoing info read from [1996 : Understanding Verilog Blocking
and Non--blocking Assignments](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/1996-CUG-presentation_nonblocking_assigns.pdf)

1. `#5 A = B;` Pulses with width less than 5 are ignored by the Simulator
2. `A = #5 B;` Input is checked every 5 time units and assigned the value immediately

**Notes**

1. All uses of delays are for simulation only and are not synthesizable.
2. The question & answer does not cover the differences when using non-blocking variants of the delays (`B <= #5 A;`, `#5 B <= A;`).

Comment: If clk wasn't a clock and it some random signal, can you tell me how the simulator reacts ? I think one has more events than other, but I dont know for sure.

Comment: Sorry, I just use the simulator as a tool and do not get involved of the nitty gritty scheduling issues it faces. On the face of it for reg declarations the two types seem to be doing the same thing, so I would have expected them to be the same for the simulator.

Comment: There are a few more additions to your answer,

#5 A = B ;    // Pulses with width less than 5 are ignored by the Simulator

A = #5 B ; // Input is checked every 5 time units and assigned the value immediately

Comment: This is what I was able to figure it from the link (SLIDE 16)
http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/1996-CUG-presentation_nonblocking_assigns.pdf